# polycharts error when using rCharts with Shiny

Tags: shiny, rcharts

*ui.R*

`showOutput("applicationsClusterRChart", lib = "polycharts")`

*server.R*

`output$applicationsClusterRChart <- renderChart({
    appCData<-mpg[,c("displ","cty")]
      clusters<-kmeans(appCData, 3)
      p1<-rPlot(displ~cty, data=appCData)
      return(p1)
    })`

DOES not output any Chart.

And when I look at the console on the browser, it throws an error:

**polychart2.standalone.js:263 Uncaught DefinitionError: Bad specification.**

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by using another rCharts renderer, called `renderChart2`, instead of `renderChart`:

```
library(rCharts)

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 

output$app <- renderChart2({                         
      # appCData <- mpg[,c("displ","cty")] # not needed for this example
      # clusters <- kmeans(appCData, 3)    # not needed for this example

      p1 <- rPlot(displ~cty, data=mpg,type='point') 
      return(p1)
    })

})
```

Besides, please note that `rPlot` requires a plot type to be explicitly stated, otherwise it will produce an empty graph. In the example above, I used `type=point`.